# ListView having ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to create an Activity containing a listView in which the rows have a listView.

here is layout structure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Only i can see header TextView in mother_row.xml but, i couldn't show row TextView in child_row.xml.

please check my MainActivity.java code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public class Item {
        List<String> ItemList;
        String ItemHeader;
        Item(String itemHeader, List<String> itemList){
            ItemHeader = itemHeader;
            ItemList = itemList;

        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView motherRowHeader;
        ListView motherListView;
    }


    public class ItemsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private List<Item> list;

        ItemsListAdapter(Context c, List<Item> l) {
            context = c;
            list = l;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;


            // reuse views
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mother_row, null);

                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.motherRowHeader
                        = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
                viewHolder.motherListView
                        = (ListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.child_listView);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            holder.motherRowHeader.setText( list.get(position).ItemHeader );

            // I think you have to inflate child list inside getview of mother
            ItemsChildListAdapter ItemAdapter 
= new ItemsChildListAdapter( MainActivity.this, list.get(position).ItemList );
            holder.motherListView.setAdapter( ItemAdapter );

            return rowView;
        }
    }

    List<Item> items;
    ListView listView;
    ItemsListAdapter myItemsListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mother_listView);

        initItems();
        myItemsListAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(myItemsListAdapter);
    }

    private void initItems() {
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        String header = "aaa";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1111111");
        list.add("2222222");
        list.add("3333333");
        list.add("4444444");
        Item item = new Item(header, list);
        items.add(item);

        list.clear();
        header = "bbb";
        list.add("1111111");
        list.add("2222222");
        list.add("3333333");
        list.add("4444444");
        item = new Item(header, list);
        items.add(item);

        list.clear();
        header = "ccc";
        list.add("1111111");
        list.add("2222222");
        list.add("3333333");
        list.add("4444444");
        item = new Item(header, list);
        items.add(item);
    }


    static class ChildViewHolder {
        TextView childRowTextView;
    }

    public class ItemsChildListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private List<String> list;

        ItemsChildListAdapter(Context c, List<String> l) {
            context = c;
            list = l;
            for(String t : list) {
                Log.d(TAG, t);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;

            // reuse views
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);

                ChildViewHolder viewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
                viewHolder.childRowTextView
                        = (TextView) rowView.findViewById( R.id.textView );
                rowView.setTag( viewHolder );
            }

            ChildViewHolder holder = (ChildViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            TextView textView = holder.childRowTextView;
            final String text = list.get(position);

            textView.setText(text);

            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return rowView;
        }
    }



}
```

It only shows like this.
[image]
How do i fix this?

Comment: I think you have to inflate child list inside getview of mother

Comment: Thank you for your tip. i will try it.

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: Vivek Mishra : I couldn't figure it out. also i edited my questions. please let me know, what is problem in my code.

Comment: you can also use expandable list view

Comment: user3676184 : Thank you for your key-word. i will find that.

Comment: use multi header listview https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders